# Is it possible to in a simple way dynamically reorder the hierarchy in a treeview in WPF using databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

Im gonna start off by explaining my title a little. 
All the information I've found about databinding to treeviews in WPF are about having an list of objects that have lists of objects that have lists of objects (and so on). 
That might be useful for some cases, but say that I have alot of objects with properties and I want to create a hierarchy sorted on different properties dynamically. 
Say I have a type like this:

```
class Car
{
internal int NumberOfCylinders{get;set;}
internal int NumberOfDoors{get;set;}
internal string Colour{get;set;}
}
```

And I want the user to be able to sort the treeview by Number of cylinders, doors and colour sometimes. Then Switch it around to Colour first and so on.

I want to believe this is doable without to much complex code because that would just be awesome...

Thanks!

/Erik

Comment: Anyone? It cant be done?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wrote my own custom implementation which works great and I learnt a few tricks while doing it. So all is good. 
For anyone who dont want to do it I can recommend you have a look at this post:

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18

Stefan Cruysberghs creates his own generic extension that he calls ASHIERARCHY(). 
I havent tried it, but it seems to do the trick really well.